# Change the encoding of R object

Tags: r

I downloaded a file:

```
download.file(http://www.redhidrosurmedioambiente.es/webgis2/incphp/txt/datostemp.php??terminal=0&fechaini=2015-12-03%2020:00&fechafin=2015-12-04%2009:00,str_filePath,"auto")
```

The file looks like: (I removed header and kept some rows to focus my problem)

```
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 11,610; 
6 - LOS REALES (MA) - (006M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 7,520;
7 - DEPÓSITO DI-1 (CA) - (007M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 15,110;
22 - MÁLAGA - PALACIO - (022M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 16,540; 
27 - RONDA (MA) - (027M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 14,880; 
62 - CERRO CAÑUELO (GR) - (062M02); 03/12/15 20:00; 9,080;
```

Then I converted it into a dataframe

```
myCurrentData <- read.csv(str_filePath,header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep=";")
```

And I got the following dataframe (check what characters appear instead of Ó, Á or Ñ)

```
                                     V1              V2      V3 V4
1     1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 20:00  11,610 NA
2        6 - LOS REALES (MA) - (006M02)  03/12/15 20:00   7,520 NA
3  7 - DEP\xd3SITO DI-1 (CA) - (007M02)  03/12/15 20:00  15,110 NA
4   22 - M\xc1LAGA - PALACIO - (022M02)  03/12/15 20:00  16,540 NA
5            27 - RONDA (MA) - (027M02)  03/12/15 20:00  14,880 NA
6 62 - CERRO CA\xd1UELO (GR) - (062M02)  03/12/15 20:00   9,080 NA
```

I tried everything. I used encoding="UTF-8" in the read.csv call, but it didnt work. I used

```
iconv(myCurrentData, from = "I tried any possible encoding here", to = "UTF8")
```

But nothing works.

I am working in Ubuntu. Could be possible an issue of my OS?

Here is the output of `Sys.getlocale()`

```
# [1] "LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8;LC‌​_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_A‌​DDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

This is my full code:

```
str_basePath <- "http://www.redhidrosurmedioambiente.es/webgis2/incphp/txt/datostemp.php?"

str_estaPar <- "terminal=0"

str_maxDateStored <- Sys.time()-50000 #Poner la fecha/hora máxima almacenada
str_parameterDate <- str_maxDateStored+(60*60)
str_finiPar <- paste("fechaini=",paste(format(str_parameterDate,"%Y-%m-%d"),format(str_parameterDate,"%H"),sep="%20"),":00",sep="")

str_maxDateStored <- Sys.time()
str_parameterDate <- str_maxDateStored
str_ffinPar <- paste("fechafin=",paste(format(str_parameterDate,"%Y-%m-%d"),format(str_parameterDate,"%H"),sep="%20"),":00",sep="")

str_url <- paste(str_basePath,paste(str_estaPar,str_finiPar,str_ffinPar,sep="&"),sep="?")


str_globalPath <- "/tmp/"
str_donwloadedFile <- "horarioJAL.txt"
str_filePath <- paste(str_globalPath,str_donwloadedFile,sep="")

download.file(str_url,str_filePath,"auto")

all_content = readLines(str_filePath)
skip_second = all_content[-1]


myCurrentData = read.csv(textConnection(skip_second), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep=";")
```

Comment: What is the output of `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: > Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Comment: Could you share the code you used to import the file? Your `download.file` is currently not correct

Comment: I get `Error in download.file(str_url, str_filePath, "auto") : 
  object 'str_filePath' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to appears with `download.file`. Here is an alternative with `RCurl`:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL(str_url)
out <- read.csv(textConnection(x), header = FALSE, skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
out[24,]
#                                   V1              V2      V3 V4
# 24 7 - DEPÓSITO DI-1 (CA) - (007M02)  04/12/15 06:00  12,580 NA
```